# Does Tobi control his teleportation consciously?

Tags: naruto

When Tobi uses his selective teleportation power that causes objects to pass through him, does he have to think about it when he does it, or is it automatic?  I'm trying to find out if he is vulnerable to a sneak attack.

I know he is able to teleport at will, but I'm wondering more about his "ghost" ability that causes objects to pass through him.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm thinking that it is voluntary, since he uses his Magekyou to do it, and it is the same technique as Kakashi's.

Also because he is able to quickly change between using (to dodge an attack) and not using it (to attack someone). Furthermore, Naruto headbutted him and he did not dodge it.

Later, Naruto hits him with a rasengan, breaking his mask and revealing his identity as Obito. Although he was 'trapped' (because of the Bijuu-dama) on the other dimension, if it were automatic, I'm guessing he wouldn't have been able to **not** dodge it, being fried by the Bijuu-dama 'back here'.

**EDIT:**
Although I say voluntary, it may be seen as **semi-automatic** (or even automatic, for that matter), in the sense that he does not actually *think* about it, but rather acts *instinctively*. However, I think it is triggered by his will, and not entirely automatic.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's somewhat semi-automatic.

When he wanted to touch Rin, he forgot to undo his jutsu, and went through her. This tells us he doesn't necessarily consciously control which parts of himself he is sending to the other dimension.

He can however activate and deactivate it on will, like a master switch.

Comment: However, that was his first use of it. He still didn't fully control it.

Comment: @JNat: That only tells me it *can* be automatic, like "switch it on, and from now on body parts teleport automatically". I don't think he consciously pays attention to the parts he needs to transport.

Comment: I'm guessing that at some point he has to force himself not to 'auto-transport' parts of his body, but that would be because he is used to doing it instinctively, rather than automatically. Also, if he can force himself not to do it, I think it is safe to assume that he also has to 'force himself' to do it (although that may come easier with practice)

Answer (score 4):

To complete the answer of JNat, I think a better example could be the fight Tobi (or Masked Man) VS Minato, while Kyûbi is attacking Konoha.

If I remember well, as the final move of the fight, Minato throws a Kunai on Tobi's face and runs to Tobi directly after : to counter it, Tobi wants to let the Kunai pass through his head with his jutsu, then come back "real" and attack Minato.

But at the exact time the Kunai has finished to pass through his head and he becomes "real" again to attack Minato, Minato uses Hiraishin - Level 2 (teleports instantly over Tobi and hits him with Rasengan).

If it was automatic, Tobi would have dodged it, but the thing that it was so fast that it hit him, proves that **he consciously uses it**.